# How to use context.cube and request in Cubism.js?

Tags: cubism.js

I am trying to learn Cubism(but could not find any tutorials) . I have few basic questions:

1. How do I use context.cube locally in Cubism. I am running Cube's evaluator locally on port 1081. I tried using "localhost" , but no luck.
2. How exactly do I use request.eq(key,'value') . Is the key from request_events collection or request_metrics?

Any help is appreciated.

[Edit]: Turns out there was a problem with cube installation. I have fixed it and now I could connect to the evaluator using "localhost:1081". However, I still can't get the correct values using metric expressions.

Here is what my data looks in mongodb('request_events' is the collection name):

Some({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51e4347f44aee763f87a1214"} , "t" : { "$date" : "2013-07-15T17:42:18.000Z"} , "d" : { "received" : { "$date" : "2013-07-15T17:42:23.817Z"} ,    "urlbase" : "egauge2962.egaug.es" , "All" : 14837.0 , "Low Voltage" : 2883.0 ,  "Lights" : 4914.0}})

I am trying to get only the values of 'All' field when received date is greater than  2013-07-15T17:42:23.817Z.

So far, this- http://`localhost:1081`/1.0/event?expression=request.ge(received,"2013-07-15T17:42:23.817Z") returns me [].